# Vqmod - writing a first file for Opencart

Tags: opencart, vqmod

I'm writing my first xml file for Opencart with VQmod. See the lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>Exibe porcento de desconto</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <vqmver>2.1.5</vqmver>
    <author>Oldman</author>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/my_theme/template/product/product.tpl">
        <operation>

      <search position="after"><![CDATA[<?php if ($price) { ?>
      <div class="price">
        <span class="txt_price"><?php echo $text_price; ?></span>
        <?php if (!$special) { ?>
        <?php echo $price; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <span class="price-old"><?php echo $price; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $special; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[ <?php echo 'Works fine!';?>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

But when I put the xml file into the vqmod/xml folder It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because You are trying to do a *multiline* search. This is not possible with current vQmod. Do only a **one line** search...

Like:

```xml
<modification>

    <id>Exibe porcento de desconto</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <vqmver>2.1.5</vqmver>
    <author>Oldman</author>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/my_theme/template/product/product.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[<?php if ($price) { ?>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[ <?php echo 'Before the price if statement!';?>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Comment: Thank you shadyyx! But in this case how can I add my script after the code that I showed?

Comment: I already can, it was not working because the file server was different from the local file. thank you shadyyx

Comment: You are welcome! Please, accept the answer so it is clear the question was answered correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Please info me in "<add><![CDATA[ myscript ]]></add>".. is working in controller,language,model but not working in view directory in admin site..vqmod V = 2.4.1 and OC V : 2.2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

VQMod will not allow the multiple line search, so if you want to search multiple line you can use "offset" property, offset="(no. of next line)"

```
<id>Exibe porcento de desconto</id>
<version>1.0</version>
<vqmver>2.1.5</vqmver>
<author>Oldman</author>

<file name="catalog/view/theme/my_theme/template/product/product.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="before" offset="7"><![CDATA[<?php if ($price) { ?>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[ <?php echo 'Works fine!';?>]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Answer (score 0):

VQMod doesn't support multiple line search. To know about vqmod options check this link: **[Opencart: Vqmod tutorial](https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/)**.